# Why won't os.environ.get return the new value set in bash profile?

Tags: python-3.x, django, bash, security, smtp

I have a django application and I recently changed a password on an email that uses the google smtp. I've updated the password in the bash profile, but when I run settings.py the os.environ.get returns the previous password in the bash profile.

old password: ABC
new password: XYZ

```
EMAILS_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASS")
print(EMAILS_HOST_PASSWORD)
```

still returns ABC instead of XYZ

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: @JoeFerndz I am unsure why my post has a -1 voting. I believe I followed the rules guidelines, and I could not find a similar post. I did search for awhile before making a post.

Comment: not sure who downvoted you. Someone in the community did it. It is possible to provide more details around your code to help the community help you with a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rely on environment variables, add `python-dotenv` to your project.

https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

You add a `.env` file to your project (you can change the filename, see my example below setting the filename) which contains the things you need to set;

```
new_password=XYZ
```

You can then load those environment variables in settings or perhaps `manage.py` like I do (depends if you only need this locally)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys

from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(filename='.environment'))


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Interesting, I will most likely use this. I am currently just testing on localhost, but I will need to update my live application. I appreciate the fix. Are you aware of what the actual issue is with os.environ.get not updating? Thank you again.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is you've got information in your bash profile, but your django app doesn't load your bash profile so you need to give it environment variables of it's own.

Answer (score 0):

bash_profile is only sourced when you login or connect with ssh i believe that might be the reason use ~/.bashrc insted

Comment: I'm currently testing it using localhost, is the solution the same?